# Connect to an API endpoint in private subnet from public subnet

Tags: reactjs, api, amazon-web-services, flask

My entire app is broken down into 3 parts:

1. Frontend, which is React.
2. Backend, which is API written in the flask language.
3. Database.

I want to host my app on AWS such that my frontend is visible to the world i.e it is in public subnet, API is hidden in a private subnet and then the DB is also in a private subnet. I can communicate with my private API instance using `curl` in my public frontend instance, but I can not communicate with my API through the React App.

Please help me out.

Comment: when you try to make the back-end communicate with react, do you get any errors? if so please provide the error. Also check your browser's console if it's shows any error.

Comment: it just says pending

Comment: It says pending where? **I'm guessing here**, most likely the problem is CORS setting. You need to configure your backend to allow CORS request. Check in the browser's console if you're seeing the CORS error.

Comment: It's not the CORS error. My backend is using CORS

Comment: mmh interesting. I am not sure then. I need some kind of error from your app to further understand your app and the issue. Sorry couldn't help.

Comment: I cannot use the private IP address of the API in my React app, because react is running on the client side.

Comment: i have the same issue, any solution?